# Duda extraña con servidor PHP TCP/IP

Tags: php

tengo una duda o una situación extraña... tengo 2 programas.

Programa 1) Servidor TCP/IP.

Programa 2) Cliente que se comunica con el TCP/IP.

Estos dos programas se comunican entre ellos el cliente le hace requerimientos al servidor y obviamente el servidor le contesta al cliente.

La comunicación se hace en 3 pasos:

--------Paso 1:

```
08-07 20:54:59.148--SendClientDataToEPos--@**@1 0 1 1 96915310*@@*   (CLIENTE)
08-07 20:54:59.664--OnResponseDataReceived—STX 0 OK ETX (SERVIDOR)
```

--------Paso 2:

```
08-08 17:58:07.021--SendClientDataToEPos--@**@2 0
FH|39||20190808|||||3|||||||||||||||||969153106|CENTRAL PARKING SYSTEM CHILE S.A.|ADMIN DE
ESTACIONAMIENTOS||||||||||AV.VITACURA3850|VITACURA|SANTIAGO||||666666666||DESCONOCIDO||||||
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||100||||||||||||||
DH|1|||||||Valor Estacionamiento|Entrada: 08/08/19 Hora: 17:54@@Salida: 08/08/19 Hora:
17:58@@Tarifa : A||||1||||100|||||100||
PP|PLAT1|EFECTIVO 100
PP|PLAT2|Suma de sus pagos 100
PP|PLAT3|Su Vuelto 0
PP|PLDT1|Gracias por su compra
PE|0001|17:58:00|000016|01|000964|00|000000
1 96915310*@@*   (CLIENTE)

08-08 17:58:07.583--OnResponseDataReceived—STX 0 La operacion ha sido exitosa 1024030 <TED
version="1.0"><DD><RE>96915310-6</RE><TD>39</TD><F>1024030</F><FE>2019-08-08</FE><RR>66666666-
6</RR><RSR>DESCONOCIDO</RSR><MNT>100</MNT><IT1>Valor Estacionamiento</IT1><CAF
version="1.0"><DA><RE>96915310-6</RE><RS>E-PARTNERS
SPA</RS><TD>39</TD><RNG><D>1024000</D><H>1024099</H></RNG><FA>2018-07-
5</FA><RSAPK><M>3Jq4KF6n0cPqXNahVcXSk032RJutTNMYKaamkWutzv+njrbF8WGzTy/4qInmlFuCp/5PSrksb5X
zGLXWkFBN4w==</M><E>Aw==</E></RSAPK><IDK>100</IDK></DA><FRMA
algoritmo="SHA1withRSA">Yl6YEJ3rKD8OULwp+ggGtQ+FWP0bRSHCcP2lsHc0LQTwxjDcOirwKAz3WXE4UzLXg6zfJ
Xzjf90IEU0ckFmhfQ==</FRMA></CAF><TSTED>2019-08-08T17:58:07</TSTED></DD><FRMT
algoritmo="SHA1withRSA">GCnRKS69Q6hzC33a1qQ5mbhiVJAYrEUHHdnFRIpqHAyoIQ2etifHECEj44N2UAgBiP/azE
JhOdY0ZkSCJTLuZw==</FRMT></TED> ETX
08-08 17:58:07.630--OnResponseDataReceived—STX 0 OK ETX   (SERVIDOR)
```

--------Paso 3:

```
08-08 17:58:07.630--SendClientDataToEPos--@**@3 0 96915310 39 1024030*@@*   (CLIENTE)
08-08 17:58:07.959--OnResponseDataReceived—STX 0 OK ETX   (SERVIDOR)
```

El cliente pide una petición al servidor y este le contesta y pasan al 2 y así sucesivamente hasta llegar al 3. Todo funciona bien si le doy doble click a ambos programas. Y aquí el problema si ejecuto ambos programas por el programador de tareas para que inicien cuando inicia windows pasa lo siguiente:

--------Paso 1:

```
08-07 20:54:59.148--SendClientDataToEPos--@**@1 0 1 1 96915310*@@*   (CLIENTE)
08-07 20:54:59.664--OnResponseDataReceived—STX 0 OK ETX (SERVIDOR)
```

--------Paso 2:

```
08-08 17:58:07.021--SendClientDataToEPos--@**@2 0          1 96915310*@@*   (CLIENTE)

ERROR
```

Como podrán ver el paso 2 le falta la cadena de caracteres gigantes por alguna razón y es por ello que ingreso a este foro esa cadena de caracteres no se viene si ejecuto el programa cuando inicia windows, pero si le doy doble click a los dos programas de una forma normal estos si corren normalmente y el paso dos funciona correctamente.

--- El código del servidor es el siguiente:

```
   <?php
   set_time_limit(0);
   $host = '127.0.0.1';
   $port = '5500';
   $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, getprotobyname('tcp'));
   socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die('Error al vincular socket con la ip en ese cliente');
   socket_strerror(socket_last_error());
   socket_listen($socket);
   $i=0;
   $dte_code = '75671692';

   $file_name = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\boleta\log_'. date('d-m-Y_h_i_s') .'.txt';
   $file = fopen($file_name,'w');
   fwrite($file, PHP_EOL ."");
   fclose($file);

   $cashier = 1;

   while(true) {
     $client[++$i] = socket_accept($socket);
     $message = socket_read($client[$i], 1024);
     $string = str_split($message, 5);

     $file = fopen($file_name,'a');
     fwrite($file, PHP_EOL ."$message");
     fclose($file);

   if($string[0] == '@**@1') {
    $response = chr(2) .'0'. chr(9) .'OK'. chr(3);
    $file = fopen($file_name,'a');
    fwrite($file, PHP_EOL ."$response");
    fclose($file);

    socket_write($client[$i], $response ."\n\r", 1024);
    $message = socket_read($client[$i], 1024);
    $string = str_split($message, 5);
    $file = fopen($file_name,'a');
    fwrite($file, PHP_EOL ."$message");
    fclose($file);
}
if($string[0] == '@**@2') {
    $string = str_split($message, 40);
    $detail = str_split($string[5], 1);
    $amount = '';

    if($detail[35] != '|')
    {
        $amount = $detail[35];
    }

    if($detail[36] != '|')
    {
        $amount = $amount.$detail[36];
    }

    if($detail[37] != '|')
    {
        $amount = $amount.$detail[37];
    }

    if($detail[38] != '|')
    {
        $amount = $amount.$detail[38];
    }

    if($detail[39] != '|')
    {
        $amount = $amount.$detail[39];
    }

    if(isset($detail[40]))
    {
        if($detail[40] != '|')
        {
            $amount = $amount.$detail[40];
        }
    }

    $amount = trim($amount);

    $connected = @fsockopen("www.google.com", 80); 

    if ($connected)
    {
        $dte = [
                'Encabezado' => [
                    'IdDoc' => [
                        'TipoDTE' => 39,
                    ],
                    'Emisor' => [
                        'RUTEmisor' => '76063822-6',
                        'CdgSIISucur' => $dte_code,
                    ],
                    'Receptor' => [
                        'RUTRecep' =>'66666666-6',
                    ],
                ],
                'Detalle' => [
                    [
                        'NmbItem' => 'Boleta Electronica',
                        'QtyItem' => 1,
                        'PrcItem' => round($amount, 0),
                    ],
                ],
            ];

        $data_string = json_encode($dte);  
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://libredte.cl/api/dte/documentos/emitir");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string); 

        $header = array(
            'Accept: application/json',
            'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode(".."),
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string)
        );

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $remote_server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);
        $results = json_decode($remote_server_output, true);

        $dte = [
               'emisor' => '76063822-6',
               'receptor' => '66666666-6',
               'dte' => 39,
               'codigo' => $results['codigo'],
            ];          

        $data_string = json_encode($dte);
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://libredte.cl/api/dte/documentos/generar?getXML=1");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string); 
        $header = array(
            'Accept: application/json',
            'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode("rcabezas:Jisparking2018"),
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string)
        );

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $remote_server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);
        
        $results = json_decode($remote_server_output, true);
        $folio = $results['folio'];

        $response = chr(2) .'0'. chr(9) .'OK'. chr(9) . $folio . chr(3);
        $file = fopen($file_name,'a');
        fwrite($file, PHP_EOL ."$response");
        fclose($file);
        socket_write($client[$i], $response ."\n\r", 1024);
        $message = socket_read($client[$i], 1024);
        $string = str_split($message, 5);
        $file = fopen($file_name,'a');
        fwrite($file, PHP_EOL ."$message");
        fclose($file);

        $servername = "jisparking.cl";
        $username = "jispar5_admin";
        $password = "Chilequedaalsur2020@";
        $bd = "jispar5_intranet";

        $con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $bd);
        if ($con->connect_error) {
            $response = "Ha fallado la conexion";
            $file = fopen($file_name,'a');
            fwrite($file, PHP_EOL ."$response");
            fclose($file);
        }
        else
        {
            // set post fields
            $post = [
                'folio' => $folio,
                'dte_code' => $dte_code,
                'cashier'   => $cashier,
                'amount'   => $amount,
                'created_at'   => date("Y-m-d h:i:s"),
            ];

            $ch = curl_init('http://www.jisparking.cl/api/transaction/store/223ewewe23');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

            // execute!
            $response = curl_exec($ch);

            // close the connection, release resources used
            curl_close($ch);

            if($response == 'Ok')
            {
                $file = fopen($file_name,'a');
                fwrite($file, PHP_EOL ."$response");
                fclose($file);
            }
            else
            {
                $file = fopen($file_name,'a');
                fwrite($file, PHP_EOL ."$response");
                fclose($file);
            }

        }
    }
    else
    {
        $response = chr(2) .'4'. chr(9) .'Error'. chr(3);
        $file = fopen($file_name,'a');
        fwrite($file, PHP_EOL ."$response");
        fclose($file);
        socket_write($client[$i], $response ."\n\r", 1024);
        socket_close($client[$i]);
    }
}

  if($string[0] == '@**@3') {
    $response = chr(2) .'0'. chr(9) .'OK'. chr(3);
    $file = fopen($file_name,'a');
    fwrite($file, PHP_EOL ."$response");
    fclose($file);
    socket_write($client[$i], $response ."\n\r", 1024);
    socket_close($client[$i]);
   }
   }
  socket_close($client[$i]);
 ?>
```

----- El programa o el código del cliente no es mio es un programa compilado ambos se comunican por el puerto 5500 y lo que sucedió fue que me dieron las directrices de como el cliente iba a mandarme información o los datos y yo lo que hice fue programar el servidor y como yo como servidor debía contestarle para que el cliente me entendiera.

MI DUDA:
-- ¿Cómo es posible que funcione correctamente cuando le doy doble clic y por el programador de tareas no? y eso que le puse los permisos máximos por el programador de tareas y coloco que lo ejecuten el administrador... si es el mismo programa que está corriendo??

Gracias!

Comment: ¿Has probado a instalar los programas como [servicios](https://www.it-swarm.dev/es/php/establecer-un-script-php-como-servicio-de-windows/973224312/) en lugar de usar el programador de tareas?

Answer (score 0):

Por una experiencia similar, el problema es que el usuario que ejecuta la tarea programada no es el mismo que desde **PHP**

Para saber esto crea un **PHP** nuevo con el código:

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('whoami');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
<?
```

Y lo ejecutas desde los dos lados, directamente desde el **PHP** y desde la **tarea programada**

Este scprit te devolverá el usuario que ejecuta el **PHP**

Una vez sepas que usuario es el correcto, tienes que modificar el inicio del servicio **Apache** con el usuario correcto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]